# Extract a dataframe from a column of dataframes (tidyverse approach)

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have been able to do some nice things with purrr to be able to work with dataframe columns within a dataframe. By which I am referring to a column of a dataframe where every cell contains a dataframe itself.

I am trying to find out the idiomatic approach for extracting one of these dataframes back out.

**Example**

```
# Create a couple of dataframes:
df1 <- tibble::tribble(~a, ~b,
                        1,  2,
                        3,  4)
df2 <- tibble::tribble(~a, ~b,
                       11, 12,
                       13, 14)

# Make a dataframe with a dataframe column containing 
# our first two dfs as cells:
meta_df <- tibble::tribble(~df_name, ~dfs, 
                           "One",     df1, 
                           "Two",     df2)
```

My question is, what is the tidyverse-preferred way of getting one of these dataframes back out of `meta_df`? Say I get the cell I want using `select()` and `filter()`:

```
library("magrittr")
# This returns a 1x1 tibble with the only cell containing the 2x2 tibble that
# I'm actually after:
meta_df %>%
  dplyr::filter(df_name == "Two") %>%
  dplyr::select(dfs)
```

This works, but seems non-tidyverse-ish:

```
# To get the actual tibble that I'm after I can wrap the whole lot in brackets
# and then use position [[1, 1]] index to get it:
(meta_df %>%
  dplyr::filter(df_name == "Two") %>%
  dplyr::select(dfs))[[1, 1]]

# Or a pipeable version:
meta_df %>%
  dplyr::filter(df_name == "Two") %>%
  dplyr::select(dfs) %>%
  `[[`(1, 1)
```

I have a feeling that this might be a situation where the answer is in `purrr` rather than `dplyr`, and that it might be a simple trick once you know it, but I'm coming up blank so far.

Comment: Perhaps with `keep` i.e. `keep(meta_df$dfs, meta_df$df_name == "One")[[1]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## better solution:

Use `tidyr::unnest()`:

```
meta_df %>%
  dplyr::filter(df_name == "Two") %>%
  dplyr::select(dfs) %>%
  tidyr::unnest()
```

## other solution:

You can use `pull` (the tidyverse way to select the column, equivalent to `$`), but it returns a one-element list of tibbles, so you need to add `%>% .[[1]]` to the end.

```
meta_df %>%
  dplyr::filter(df_name == "Two") %>%
  dplyr::pull(dfs) %>% .[[1]]
```

Comment: Just a note on the second `pull()` solution here: I think the `select()` line can be dropped to achieve the same result.